# java android Фоновое распознавание текста

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Находил такую реализацию распознавания текста (используя гугл сервисы) [архив с исходником](http://www.indragni.com/android/VoiceRecognitionActivity.zip). Там открывается подобное окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то это делать без открытия окна? И чтобы работало при выключенном экране смартфона?

Answer (score 0):

я не стал скачивать ваш архив, но думаю что это возможно. Если исходники в виде android-проекта, то просто запустите функции, распознавания речь в сервисе. Возможно это грубое решение, но оно рабочее. Настроив сервис должным образом, и связав его с вашим приложением, можно добиться, что при погашенном экрана, при возникновении команды, будет просыпаться телефон и реагировать на команду. Другой вопрос, будет ли это эффективно? Получится неоптимизированный демон, жрущий батарею. Если найдете иное решение, пжлста, опишите его в конце.